# POST and GET at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

hello everyone sorry but am just beginner in php , mysql ... i was developing question and answer website which i have page for all Question (Q.php) and page for displaying a specific question (QR.php) and get information according to data sent from Q.php via url ($_GET['start'] i  also have page to confirm that the answer is already submitted .... but i got error when entering the id from get method and the message from post method ... any answer will be appreciated

Q.php

```
<?php


  include("pagination.php");

    if(isset($res))
    {
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
                    echo '<div class="shop-item">' ;
                    echo '  <div class="price">' ;
                    echo  $result['Inquirer'] ;
                    echo '  </div>' ;

                    echo '  <div class="price">' ;
                    echo  $result['question'] ;
                    echo '  </div>' ;

                    echo ' <div class="actions"> ';
    echo '<input type="button" class="btn btn-large " value="More Info"  onclick="window.location=\'QR.php?start=' . urlencode($result['id']) . ' \';" />';
 echo '</div> ';
 echo ' </div> ';
        }

    }
?>
```

QR.php

```
<form action="QRR.php" method="POST"> 
<div class="blog-post blog-single-post">
<div class="single-post-title">
<h2>Post Your Answer</h2>
</div>

<div  align="Right">

<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name ="answer" id="Test">       
</textarea>

<br>
<div class="actions">

<?php echo '<input type="button" class="btn btn-large " value="Post Answer" onclick="window.location=\'QRR.php?start=' . urlencode($_GET['start']) . ' \';" />'; ?>
</div>
</div>

 </div>
 </form>
```

QRR.php

```
<?php
// variables 
$answer=$_REQUEST['answer'];
require ("coonection.php");
$FURL = $_REQUEST['hi'];


//query 
$query = "INSERT INTO `answers`(`answer_id`, `question_id`, `answer`, `answerer`, `rate`, `dnt`) VALUES ('','$FURL','$answer','ahmed','',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$data=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if($data)
{
echo "Your Questions Has Been Successfully Added ";
}
?>
```

if i removed passing hi from QR to QRR answer stored  //$answer

if i removed storing answer from the text area the id from url stroed //$FURL

Comment: Don't you hate it when people vote your question down but don't say why? I'll vote it up. They probably voted it down because you cannot use POST and GET at the same time.

Comment: not clear at all. try to point ou where the problem occur in code?

Comment: you absolutely can use get and post at the same time.  I do it all the time.  for example.. when submitting a form via post, you can set the url in action with parameters, which make it a get.  However, if you are submitting a form.  you may not have some inputs set to get and some set to post.

Comment: i got error in QRR.php in line $answer=$_REQUEST['answer']; @anantkumarsingh ty

Comment: so why i got the error in the query in QRR @AdamJosephLooze ty

Comment: instead of having the url in your submit button, try adding this to your form opening tag..  `action="QRR.php?start=<?php print urlencode($_GET['start']); ?>"`

Comment: @Adam Joseph Looze: You're right of course, sorry I wasn't thinking. I though of a form, and forgot about the URL.

Comment: Also, you are insterting into table `answers` and i see you are setting `answer_id`.  i wouldnt include this in your query, and in your database set this field to auto incriment and primary key.

Comment: i did all what you said and yes it work @AdamJosephLooze you the best with no argument xD

Comment: Your welcome.  i am submitting an answer with sme sugestions

Comment: my honor @AdamJosephLooze is it allowed if i asked you for your email here or i gunna be banned ? :D

Comment: you are welcome to contact me via gmail.  i use google hangouts for code stuff.  adam.ncmich.edu@gmail.com.  if you msged me on hangouts, i would be happy to help you with your page

Comment: its not my page only it's my graduation poject thnQ very much brother <3 made my day :D

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze when retreive what querry i should youse with pagination !

Comment: Pagination is a different ball game.  The easiest method i can think of would be, say.  20 at a time.. so on your page you would write something like `SELECT (your stuff) FROM (your table) WHERE id<'20' && id>'0'`
and then on page 2 you would have the query change to `WHERE id<'40' && id>'20'`  and then you could set up a URL var that says `?page=2` (page number).  and `if(isset($_GET['page'])){ $pageNumber = $_GET['page']; }` and then set your queries based on that.  I know being a beginner, that may not make sense.

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze  or may make :D i did it bro <3 check your mail i sent ScreenShoot for you :D sry am new here cant fine how to upload pictures ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt the most beautiful code, as i just copied yours and made a few modifications.. but this form will submit back to the same page, and the php will run and insert ONLY if the form is submitted.

if(isset($_POST['answer'])) says "if the variable _POST answer is set, run the php code and insert.. if it is not set, do nothing.

You will notice the form action is left blank, you can set it to the page name yo are on.. as the form will send the variables to the same page.  This is a good way of doing it because if there are errors, you can prepopulate the input or textareas with the code they just typed in.

```
<?php
// variables 
if(isset($_POST['answer'])){
    $answer=$_POST['answer'];
    require ("coonection.php");
    $FURL = $_POST['hi']; // there is no input name 'hi' set in your form.  so this code will fail due to that.


    //query 
    $query = "INSERT INTO `answers`(`question_id`, `answer`, `answerer`, `rate`, `dnt`) VALUES ('$FURL','$answer','ahmed','',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    $data=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if($data){
        echo "Your Questions Has Been Successfully Added ";
    }
}
?>
```

`
you will see i removed your answer_id.  if you use this code, make sure that field is set to primary auto increment in your database.

```
<form action="" method="POST"> 
<div class="blog-post blog-single-post">
<div class="single-post-title">
<h2>Post Your Answer</h2>
</div>

<div  align="Right">

<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="answer" id="Test"></textarea>

<br>
<div class="actions">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-large " value="Post Answer">Post Answer</button>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

NOTE: both of these snippets will go in the same page.